# transform <object> to <video> javascript

Tags: javascript, object, flash, video

Mine is just a question, maybe an idiot question, but I would like to know if its possible to transform a tag `<object>` containing a video, directly to the tag `<video>`

Thanks all. 
I appreciate any help.

My `<object>` video:

```html
<object width="100%" height="100%" id="player_api" data="my-data-url" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="bgcolor" value="#000000">
<param name="flashvars" value='config={"playlist":[{"url":"my-video-url","autoPlay":true}],"clip":{"autoPlay":true},"plugins":{"controls":{"url":""}},"playerId":"player"}'>
</object>
```

To something like:

```
<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176">
  <source src="my-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: In the flashvars param, shouldn't the quotes be escaped?

Comment: Why do you want to do this programmatically? Why not simply change your HTML source code?

Comment: @LucaKiebel I don't think so, this code come from a default php shortcode, and it works as it is. I don't know more...

Comment: @JeremyThille this <object> come from an ajax call that calls a php shortcode containing the video source coming from an external service. YES, the story is long and bad :D :D so I can't modify it direcly

Comment: do you know what format will be the video file? My idea is to delete the <Object> and create & insert <Video> on that place.

Comment: @NedkoDimitrov yes it is .mp4. Ok thanks for your hint, I will have a lot of work doing that. I will think about it.

Comment: Your `<object>` code is embedding some video-player app that works via the Flash plugin. Use your browser's **Developer Tool** to check the "Network" tab/section. This will list all the loaded files on the page. See if an MP4 is listed and then copy it's link URL into your own `<video>` tag...